# How to create a C Program in a GUI window?

Tags: c, user-interface, iteration

I have a bunch of simple programs that I would like to display in a GUI window rather than a DOS terminal.  How can I accomplish this? Do I need to call upon a library or what?  Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you imagine "Displaying a program" would work?

Comment: What kind of interaction does the "simple" programs have with the user? input, output?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a library to do this; the C language does not define any windowing or GUI constructs.  Since you're talking about DOS terminals, I'm assuming that you're in Windows, and so you might want to look at the Windows API, which is a C library with all sorts of powerful windowing tools.  You might also want to look at one of the many wrapper libraries that are layered on top of this API, like MFC or WPF.

Comment: `CreateWindow` and `CreateWindowEx` for example.

Comment: What is even the point of the C language then?  Does it have any specialty?

Comment: @Erich- It's not that C can't do windowing (it certainly can; I think both Microsoft's Windows API and the X windowing system are written in C!), it's that there's no *standard library* for doing windowing in C.  If you want to do windowing in C, you need to get a special library to handle it for you because you're likely going to be interfacing with OS-specific code.

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a windows application project in your compiler, any compiler i know has that option, and include the windows.h library (#include  ).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the gtk library http://www.gtk.org and if you feel comfortable with c++ i recommend you wxwidgets GUI framework http://www.wxwidgets.org.